# Is async in javascript concurrent or parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, callstack, event-loop

JavaScript code runs on a single thread, in event loop when method push to web apis return callback function to queue, listener queue and callstack is empty push callback function execute it in callstack, so the asynchronous execution is really just changing the execution order of the functions? Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Due to JavaScript being single-threaded, it is technically only **concurrent**, not **parallel**. That is, no two instructions are ever executed at the same time, but the event loop allows us to coordinate the order in which instructions are executed such that certain instructions are **non-blocking**.

To see why this is useful, consider the following sequence of steps:

1. Make a call to an API
2. Do some other work

Step 1 could take quite some time, and we may want to do some other work in the meantime while we wait for it to complete, making it a **blocking** call. In a purely sequential world, this means that step 2 will not execute until step 1 has been completed. In comparison, if we make this **asynchronous**, and therefore **non-blocking**, we can execute steps 1 and 2 **concurrently**. This happens because the event loop will run an iteration of our synchronous code first (step 2), **then** run our asynchronous code (step 1) - it is changing the order instructions are executed in such a way that our code is **non-blocking**. Interestingly, this means an asynchronous delay of 0 seconds will run **after** the next synchronous iteration of code.

Say we introduce step 3, in which we need the response from the API call in step 1. To do this, we can use an **async-await**, which will be **blocking** until step 1 completes. This is not purely sequential, as Step 2 does not need to wait for step 1 to complete, but at step 3 we are able to create a synchronous point in our code via **async-await**. So we are able to keep our code **non-blocking** where it matters, and still introduce a particular sequence of events.